# Invalid data type PL SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Why am I getting following errors with this query?

```
-- NOT NULL
  ALTER TABLE employee
  MODIFY FirstName NOT NULL;
```

> Error starting at line : 23 in command - ALTER TABLE employee   MODIFY
>   FirstName (NOT NULL) Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid
>   datatype
>   00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Table EMPLOYEE altered.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax. Remove brackets.

```
SQL> create table employee (first_name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> alter table employee modify first_name not null;

Table altered.

SQL>
```